# Showing this sum converges (sum of normal tail probabilities)?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, self-learning

Let $S_n \sim N(0,n)$ so that $S_n$ is the partial sum process of standard normal random variables.

My objective is to prove:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(S_n \geq (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2 n \log log n }) < \infty$$

for all $\epsilon > 0$.

I cannot use the law of iterated logarithm, as the reason I want to prove the above inequality is to prove a weaker form of iterated logarithm ($\leq 1$ instead of $=1$).

My attempt has been to bound the tail probabilities using known inequalities for standard normal. Firstly, we rewrite it as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(S_n/\sqrt{n} \geq (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2 \log \log n }) < \infty$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\Phi((1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2 \log \log n })) < \infty$$

Inequalities I know of:

$$1-\Phi(x) \leq x^{-1} e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$$

$$1-\Phi(x) \leq \frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2/2}$$

But neither is enough to bound the sum by a convergent sequence. Alternatively, I also know that

$1-\Phi(x) \sim \phi(x)$ but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: In the first inequality for $1-\Phi(x)$ you have stated there is also an inequality in the opposite direction with a different constant. It appears therefore that the result you are trying to prove is actually false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

This cannot be shown in the way you're trying. Indeed, the best possible this way is $\Omega(\sqrt{\log n})$. This is because a commensurate lower bound to the gaussian CDF exists:

$$1 - \Phi(x) \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} e^{-x^2/2}$$

(to show this, integrate by parts one more time in the proof of the first upper bound you state).

One reason you are failing is the following: with the proof strategy, the following statement would also follow: Consider independent Gaussians $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$ Then $\{Z_n \ge (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2\log \log n} \}$ occurs only finitely often a.s. It is intuitive that this is false (for a proof, use the lower bound above and B-C). The LIL truly uses the fact that one is dealing with a sum of Gaussians, by exploting the correlations between $S_n$ and $S_{(1+c)n}$ for small $c$.

Comment: That makes sense. But that is strange, as this is an old exam question, and I don't think it would be that difficult.

Comment: Well, maybe, since it's an exam question and since the LIL is pretty standard material for a grad prob. class, it's possible that they expect one to reproduce the upper bound proof from this?